# Каково отличие объявления стилей без пробелов (.class1.class2) от объявления с пробелом (.class1 .class2)?

Tags: css3

Например когда классы устанавливаешь близко друг к другу код работает по другому.
Пример:

```
.sb_header.button_cont
```

будет работать иначе, чем

```
.sb_header .button_cont
```

Comment: исходя из классов - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/hs96xbro/

Comment: Зачем классы располагать близко друг другу - чтобы повысить вес селектора

Comment: Почитай будет полезно... https://webformyself.com/30-selektorov-css-kotorye-nuzhno-zapomnit/

Comment: Полезно, но ответа там нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом случае, с нотацией без пробела, стили будут применены к элементу, у которого есть **и** класс `sb_header` **и** `button_cont`, а во втором, когда названия классов разделены пробелом, - к элементу с классом `button_cont`, который **является потомком** элемента с классом `sb_header`.

Пробел при объявлении стилей, наравне с `>`, `,` и прочими, является *оператором*.